# How to update random 4 rows in a table using row level locking with Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, locking

We are planning to use a simple flat table without references as a transactional data store in Postgres. The table is constantly being updated from different threads. We need to select maximum 4 minimum 1 row from the table, lock it, do an update on the status field and release the lock. Ideally this should be the way that concurrent queries are not blocking each other, every query can modify its own rowset.

After reading the documentation I think I could do it with:

```
SELECT user_id FROM rooms LIMIT 1 INTO local_user_id 
WHERE user_status=0 FOR UPDATE;

UPDATE rooms  SET user_status = 1 
WHERE user_id = local_user_id;
```

However, I need to update 1-4 users at the time, bundling all the max 4 users into a single transaction would drop the number of transactions to 1/4th best case (assuming most of the select result in 4 users). What is the idiomatic way of solving this with Postgres 9.6?

UPDATE1:

What I am trying to achieve here is a queue like behaviour, each thread gets a few items and processes those, while other threads can happily read from the rest of the rows and process other 4 rows in a concurrent and parallel way.

Comment: What's the problem with writing `LIMIT 4`? That will give you 4 or less result rows.

Comment: And how can I iterate over the 4 ids?

Comment: In your favorite programming language (or stored procedure language like [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html) or [PL/Perl](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plperl.html) if you want to write a database function).

Comment: The `update` will lock the rows anyway. Why do you think you need an additional explicit lock?

Comment: Because I want to block the other threads to be able to read those 4 rows yet being able to read the rest of the rows. Is this how row level locking works?

Comment: You can only block those other "reads" if they also do a `select ... for update`. A plain `select` (without for update) will not be blocked by that.

Comment: Yes correct, the other select are for update too. Thanks for the clarification. I think this is going to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store chosen ids in array:

```
WITH x AS (
       SELECT user_id
         FROM rooms
        WHERE user_status=0
        ORDER BY random()
        LIMIT 4
          FOR UPDATE
)
SELECT array_agg(user_id) FROM x;
```

And after that update in one query or individually.

Comment: Or simply replace the `select array_agg()` with `update ... set ... where id in (select user_id from x)`

Comment: If I understand correctly between lock and update might be some time/calculation - because for what we need LOCK?

Comment: Thanks Roman, what I am trying to achieve here is: block the other readers from accessing the 4 rows I am doing a time consuming operations on, yet being able to execute queries returning different set of rows to each thread. If I have 16 rows matching than 4 threads  will process 4 rows each, in a concurrent and parallel fashion.